# What is the asset Type 0 for containers in yodlee interactive?

Tags: php, laravel, yodlee

```
assetType = 1 indicates asset

assetType = 2 indicates liability

assetType = 0 indicates what ?

Yodlee Interactive
```

**For asset types refer the following link**

https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getAllSiteAccounts

See Sample `JSON Response to find assetType = 0`

Answer (score 0):

assetType= 0 is for container type bills, miles(rewards). Here are some sites for e.g., British Airways Executive Club, AT&T, Vodafone etc.

Comment: For containers assetType = 1 is an asset, assetType = 2 is an liability . Likewise is there any name for assetType = 0.